# Error with Next JS api (app directory) request.json()

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const data = await request.json();

  console.log(data);
  return NextResponse.json({ foo: "boo" });
}
```

next version =  "next": "13.4.2"

error:  getting error at await request.json()

```
error SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6571:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6545:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1211:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: because request cannot be parsed as json? Console.log request first and you will see why

Comment: Shouldn't it automatically handle the error and set the data as 'unknown' if no JSON body is given?

Comment: @Chinmoykr No you have to `try/catch`

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when you try to get body from an api end point but you are not sending any data in body. To remain on the safe side, always use it in try catch

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try{
     const data = await request.json();
     console.log(data);
  }
  catch(e) {
     /* you error message */
  }
  return NextResponse.json({ foo: "boo" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be with the way you are sending the request... I got the same problem when i was sending post request with postman using formdata and then used `request.json()` to parse the body in next. If that is the case you should use `request.formData()` or raw body with json encoding on postman.